# How to use XNode.ReadFromAsync()

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently using `el = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement` to read XML data from a socket connection. This works fine, except when the socket stops to transmit any more data. In this case the call blocks and does not return. 
Now I wanted to try `XNode.ReadFromAsync` (as described in [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfromasync?view=netcore-3.1)).
But VisualStudio (2017, 2019) says: 'XNode' does not contain a definition for 'ReadFromAsync'. I also cannot find any useful sample that shows how ReadFromAsync() would be put to work, in fact I cannot find any sample at all.

1. Would using `XNode.ReadFromAsync` solve my problem, i.e. the call would return even if there is no more data available on the socket?
2. How would I need to use it in my VisualStudio project?

Comment: See [Applies to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfromasync?view=netcore-3.1#moniker-applies-to) section. This method is available starting with .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: You can abort the execution of this method by using `CancellationToken`. For example, when a certain timeout is reached, if the data is not received for a long time.

Comment: @Alexander - do you have or know sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now ready to answer my own question. Like Alexander mentioned before you need to use a Framework that actually contains `XNode.ReadFromAsync` (e.g. NET Core).
I used a timer to cancel reading to get back control in order to close and re-open the socket I was reading from.

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
System.Timers.Timer timeoutTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);        // check if ReadFrom(reader) times out
timeoutTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => ParseTimeout(sender, e, cancellation); 
XElement el = null;
AggregateException tex = null;
try
{
     timeoutTimer.Start();
     Task<XNode> t = XNode.ReadFromAsync(reader, cancellation.Token); 
     el = t.Result as XElement;  
     tex = t.Exception;
     timeoutTimer.Stop();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    el = new XElement("DoCloseStream", "ExceptionXElementAfterReadFromFails"+ ex.Message + "=" + tex?.Message);
}
if (el != null)
    yield return el;
...
...
private static void ParseTimeout(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, CancellationTokenSource cancellation)
{
     cancellation.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: You can use [CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter?view=netcore-3.1) method instead of Timer.